# Flot graph align the data points in equidistance

Tags: jquery, flot

How can i make the points align in equidistant in flotgraph when there is a line chart view on data from weekly basis

[image]

Any method which is in the flot graph plugin??

Comment: It's all in your data, flot will plot what you provide.

Comment: i'l be sending one data but what should i do for the space between 2 data points

Comment: The data series is an array of points, where each point consists of (at least) an x- and y-coordinate: `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`. If you want your datapoints to be evenly spaced on the x-axis (that's what you want, right?) you have to adjust the x-coordinates in the data series.

Comment: "data":[[1391193000000,0],[1393612200000,0],[1396290600000,0],[1398882600000,361.97]
 this is the way iam sending the data, and there's no where i can send the x co ordinates.. can u please elaborate

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73nWU/1/) using your data, which shows equidistant data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use have weekly values with timestamps exactly one week apart then your points will be equidistant on the xaxis.

In general if you want equidistant points in your chart where the data is not equidistant, use the category plugin ([example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html), [example code](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/examples/categories/index.html)).

Basic code:

```
var data = [ ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9] ];

$.plot("#div", [ data ], {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "categories"
    }
});
```

Comment: i'l be using the mode, but the date is dynamic.. the logic is the week is from mon to sun, so if the 1st date chosen by the user is sun then only sun is plotted in first point, next point contains from next day i.e mon-sun